# When I render an image it comes out different than what I see in the viewport. How can i fix this?

Tags: 3d-view, image

[image: **As you can see the bevels in the viewport on the front pyramid are much smaller compared to the rendered image. This is an Eevee render**]

As you can see the bevels in the viewport on the front pyramid are much smaller compared to the rendered image. This is an Eevee render.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any modifiers (e.g. subdivision), which have different parameter settings for "Viewport" and "Render"?

If so, setting the number to the same value should give you a consistent result!